# Using mcrypt_create_iv to create salt?

Tags: php, salt

I'm currently in the process of learning how hashing + salting works, I'm currently using this code on PHP to generate 'salt'

```
function calculateSalt(){
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
return $iv;
}
```

In theory this should return a good salt for hashing my passwords with. When I applied it to my small database of test passwords It seem'd like it looked pretty secure and unique although as this is a very low amount of test passwords I was wondering If this is an acceptable way to generate a good, unique salt or if `mcrypt_create_iv` was bad practice. From what I can tell it's main purpose isn't for salting but would It be bad If I used it for this purpose?

Note this database is not of public passwords, just test cases. Here is the salt + hashes using the above technique.
[image: salted + hashed passwords using above technique]

Comment: I think that's how bcrypt works internally... let me find a link for you.

Comment: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);` .. but for passwords you can use `password_hash()` instead.

Comment: Kind of. Check this [ircmaxell compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php). It uses `mcrypt_create_iv()` as default salter if no salt was passed.

Comment: In the core it either uses `php_win32_get_random_bytes()` or reads directly from `/dev/urandom`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `mcrypt_create_iv()` is technically meant to create initialisation vectors for symmetric encryption, it can be used to generate random salts just as well.

However, for passwords, you should be using a password hashing function instead:

```
$hash = password_hash('my difficult password');
```

It uses [`crypt()`](http://php.net/crypt) internally and, depending on the platform, will either read from `/dev/urandom` directly or use [`php_win32_get_random_bytes()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/win32/winutil.c#80) to generate a salt if none is provided.

One advantage in terms of storage is that both the hash and salt are stored in a single opaque string.

See also: [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash)

Comment: I genuinely hope that nobody takes this answer seriously. Hashing your passwords is not the same thing as salting them. Salting a password is not a way to not hash your password and vice versa. Special cryptographic hardware and high-performance GPU's can crack thousands of hashes in mere seconds. This is why we salt passwords and implement key stretching.

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins hashing simply refers to the behaviour of producing an irreversible result from a given input; the difficulty in verification is different for each hashing algorithm, the one used for bcrypt is particularly hard.

Comment: Id agree with this when we are talking about bcrypt, but we can never assume that everyone will use bcrypt. So it is always nice to promote best practices and fully inform that you should always be salting and key stretching. Especially since unlike CPU's, GPU's are always getting more powerful at an exponential rate.

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins I wasn't assuming bcrypt was being used, I'm saying that it should be used :)

Comment: amen brother! bcrypt is a beautiful thing as far as cryptography goes.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a copy of my RandomBytes function. It uses the most random source available on your system.

$count is how many bytes you want.

$base64 is true to output base64, false to output a binary string.

$sessionIdSafe is true to modify the base64 in such a way that it is still valid for using as a sessionid in PHP. It changes the base64 character set from A-Za-z0-9+/ to A-Za-z0-9,- , and strips any '=' padding characters from the end of the string.

```
function randomBytes($count, $base64 = false, $sessionIdSafe = false)
{
    $bytes = '';

    if(is_readable('/dev/urandom') && ($urandom = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')) !== false)
    {
        $bytes = fread($urandom, $count);
        fclose($urandom);
    }

    if((strlen($bytes) < $count) && function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv'))
    {
        // Use MCRYPT_RAND on Windows hosts with PHP < 5.3.7, otherwise use MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
        // (http://bugs.php.net/55169).
        $flag = (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<') && strncasecmp(PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) == 0) ? MCRYPT_RAND : MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM ;
        $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv($count,$flag);
    }

    if((strlen($bytes) < $count) && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes'))
    {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($count);
    }

    if ((strlen($bytes) < $count) && class_exists('COM'))
    {
        // Officially deprecated in Windows 7
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        try
        {
            /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
            $CAPI_Util = new COM('CAPICOM.Utilities.1');
            if(is_callable(array($CAPI_Util,'GetRandom')))
            {
                /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */
                $bytes = $CAPI_Util->GetRandom(16,0);
                $bytes = base64_decode($bytes);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
        }
    }

    if (strlen($bytes) < $count)
    {
        mt_srand(microtime(true)*1000000);
        $bytes = '';
        $random_state = microtime();
        if (function_exists('getmypid'))
            $random_state .= getmypid();

        // for every 16 bytes that we need
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16)
        {
            // generate 16 bytes at a time in hexadecimal
            $random_state =
                md5(microtime() . $random_state . mt_rand());
            // convert the hex into binary. using pack so that the code is backwards
            // compatible with pre php-5 since md5(data,raw) is only available in 5
            $bytes .=
                pack('H*', md5($random_state));
        }
        $bytes = substr($bytes, 0, $count);
    }

    if ($base64)
    {
        $result = base64_encode($bytes);
        if($sessionIdSafe)
        {
            $result = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-',','),$result);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        return $bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: ha ha. I suppose the base64 and sessionid modifiers don't need to be there, but they only add 7 lines of code to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on @Jack's answer if I had enough rep but I don't so... following his answer you can look at [Password Compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for generating password which is using the password_* functions being worked on for PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing your own user login system it is **very important** to follow well-established guidelines and not to attempt to *reinvent the wheel* concerning the crypto. Here's a very [good article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on how to do password hashing and salting.

It also comes with the following PHP example:
(I'll copy it here in case the [original source](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode) goes down.)

```
<?php
/*
 * Password Hashing With PBKDF2 (http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).
 * Copyright (c) 2013, Taylor Hornby
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, 
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation 
 * and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE 
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR 
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF 
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS 
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN 
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) 
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

// These constants may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);

function create_hash($password)
{
    // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" .
        base64_encode(pbkdf2(
            PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
            $password,
            $salt,
            PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
            PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE,
            true
        ));
}

function validate_password($password, $correct_hash)
{
    $params = explode(":", $correct_hash);
    if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
       return false;
    $pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
    return slow_equals(
        $pbkdf2,
        pbkdf2(
            $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
            $password,
            $params[HASH_SALT_INDEX],
            (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
            strlen($pbkdf2),
            true
        )
    );
}

// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
    $diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
    {
        $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
    }
    return $diff === 0;
}

/*
 * PBKDF2 key derivation function as defined by RSA's PKCS #5: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt
 * $algorithm - The hash algorithm to use. Recommended: SHA256
 * $password - The password.
 * $salt - A salt that is unique to the password.
 * $count - Iteration count. Higher is better, but slower. Recommended: At least 1000.
 * $key_length - The length of the derived key in bytes.
 * $raw_output - If true, the key is returned in raw binary format. Hex encoded otherwise.
 * Returns: A $key_length-byte key derived from the password and salt.
 *
 * Test vectors can be found here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt
 *
 * This implementation of PBKDF2 was originally created by https://defuse.ca
 * With improvements by http://www.variations-of-shadow.com
 */
function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
        trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.', E_USER_ERROR);
    if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
        trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.', E_USER_ERROR);

    if (function_exists("hash_pbkdf2")) {
        // The output length is in NIBBLES (4-bits) if $raw_output is false!
        if (!$raw_output) {
            $key_length = $key_length * 2;
        }
        return hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output);
    }

    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

    $output = "";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
        // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
        $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
        // first iteration
        $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
        // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
        for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
        }
        $output .= $xorsum;
    }

    if($raw_output)
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    else
        return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}
?>
```

Comment: You know there is a built in function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which can calculate BCrypt hashes? This function should be prefered, because native code runs faster than PHP code and you can do more rounds.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: How often do you authenticate your users to be that concerned with performance? Also one cannot expect everyone to be running PHP v.5.5.0.

Comment: This is not a question of performance, this is a question of security. Normally you decide how much time an authentication may consume, this depends on your server and on the number of users. With a faster algorithm you can do more rounds in this time, and get more secure hashes. Also there is a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions.